# Entityframework model first, use getters and setters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using entityframework 6, with a model first .edmx file approach.

I would like to use the get {} and set{} because I want to modify the data when it is saved and I would like to modify it again when it's retrieved from the database before it is shown anywhere.

Since the class is autogenerated, is there any way I can use the get / set without my changes being overwritten?  Perhaps since it's a partial class? I can't seem to find a way to override them, though.

Comment: Have you tried `Code First From Database` in the ADO.NET Entity Data Model options, rather than using the edmx?

Comment: @Jonesy It's an existing old project.

Comment: @user1308743 It think what the last commenter was suggesting was that if the DB has been generated from the model, you can work backwards and generate the model from the DB.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the `get/set` logic for existing properties? If so, as you noticed, you can't do that directly in the class since your changes will be overwritten next time the object is auto-generated. In situations like this, it makes sense to have two different entity types: one created by the model and one that represents the entity to the client. For example if you have a `DBCustomer` object, you'll create your own `Customer` entity, populate it with `DBCustomer`, and implement your logic in it.

Comment: @Asad I suppose I could do that but it would be a significant amount of work and testing for the size of the project and would rather avoid it

Comment: @user1308743 It would require a significant amount of testing, as does any change, but it would involve barely any work. You can use existing tools, such as [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d663b99-ed3b-481d-b7bc-b947d2457e3c), to generate a code based Entity Framework model, then modify the POCOs to your liking.